# What are side shields on ballistic eyewear seen in recent Olympics shooting?

Tags: olympics, shooting

Please, notice the side shields at this goggles (image taken from Olympics video  which can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgyBFemjeuQ), shown @ 2:48).

[image: women 10m air pistol screenshot]
There were multiple such things shown during that contest and they definitely not look like either support frame or anything that can be found on typical ballistic eye wear. On the shown occasions, they seem to protrude forward from the frame.. what are they for? something to do with the field of vision or unnecessary side glares?

Comment: I would guess protection against light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are called [blinkers or blinders](http://hunting.about.com/od/guns/ss/olympicairrifle_4.htm).

Just as horses sometimes wear them to narrow their field of vision, shooters do the same.

Having blinders on the side of the eyewear helps the shooter maintain down-range vision.  As well as the side blinders, some shooters also have a blinder over their non-dominant eye.

Note that the size of blinders is governed by rules.

> "Side Blinders attached to the hat, cap, shooting glasses, or to a head band, not exceeding 40mm deep are permitted. These blinders must not extend further forward than to a line from the center of the forehead."

Answer (score 4):

Most people I know who use them state that it is just to reduce all distractions to a minimum, such as light, movement etc.